# Android KitKat Bluetooth ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED not working

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a weird issue, where my broadcast receiver is not receiving the ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED on android 4.4.2.

But I have another android phone with 4.1.2 and it works correctly.

Is this a known issue?

Here is my AndroidManifest :

```
       <receiver android:name="com.example.MyClass$BluetoothBroadcastReceiver" 
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

I removed the `android:enabled="true"` and `android:exported="false"` and now it works on both 4.4.2 and 4.1.2

Comment: so this receiver need to be exported